# Change format of printbibliography title

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting

I want to generate several different blocks of bibliographies using the printbibliography command, but I don't want each block to be formatted like a chapter, as shown in the MWE.

I would like the format of the titles of each block to be more like a section and not be on separate pages.

MWE:

MWE.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}
\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\bibliography{references}
\nocite{*}

\newrobustcmd{\mklocalfilter}[1]{%
  \defbibfilter{#1}{%
    segment=0
    or
    segment=\therefsegment
  }}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\lipsum[1-3]

\printbibliography[keyword={algebra},heading=subbibliography,heading=bibintoc,title={Bibliografía de aritmética y álgebra}]
\printbibliography[keyword={calculo},heading=bibintoc,title={Bibliografía de cálculo}]

\end{document}
```

references.bib

```
@book{algebra_1,
title={Álgebra Lineal},
author={Grossman, S.L. and Ibarra, J.},
year={2015},
publisher={McGRAWHILL, Madrid},
keywords={algebra}
}

@book{algebra_2,
title={Álgebra Lineal y Geometría},
author={Hernández, E. and Vázquez, M.J. and Zurro, M.A.},
year={2012},
publisher={Pearson, Madrid},
keywords={algebra}
}

@book{algebra_3,
title={Álgebra básica},
author={Queysanne, M.},
year={1975},
publisher={Vicens-Vives, Barcelona},
keywords={algebra}
}

@book{algebra_4,
title={Elementos de Análisis Algebraico},
author={Rey, J.},
year={1966},
publisher={Biblioteca Matemática, Madrid},
keywords={algebra}
}

@book{calculo_1,
title={Cálculo. Una variable},
author={Rogawski, J.},
year={2012},
publisher={Rerverté, Barcelona},
keywords={calculo}
}

@book{calculo_2,
title={Calculus},
volume={Volumen I},
author={Salas, Hille y Etgen},
year={2002},
publisher={Rerverté, Barcelona},
keywords={calculo}
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: instead of `\bibliography{references}` you should use the proper biblatex macros: `\addbibressource{references.bib}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\defbibheading` to use a section instead of a chapter:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}
\usepackage{titlesec, titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\addbibresource{references.bib}
%\bibliography{references}
\nocite{*}

\newrobustcmd{\mklocalfilter}[1]{%
  \defbibfilter{#1}{%
    segment=0
    or
    segment=\therefsegment
  }}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
  \section{#1}
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\lipsum[1-3]

\printbibliography[keyword={algebra},title={Bibliografía de aritmética y álgebra}]
\printbibliography[keyword={calculo},title={Bibliografía de cálculo}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!! And one more question: what changes should I make to don't show section numbers aside bibliography titles?

Comment: @Á.Garzón You can get unnumbered sections with `\section*{`

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks!!

Comment: @Á.Garzón You're welcome!